# How to get the last inserted value in a column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any function I can use to get the last inserted value in my column `thread_id`?

```
$result =  DB::insert("Insert Into $this->table (thread_id, sender_id, subject, message, date_sent)
                Select COALESCE(max(thread_id),0)+1 , ? , concat('Re: ',subject), ? , now() FROM $this->table Limit 1",array( $sender_id  ,  $message) );
```

something like `insertGetId`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139935/laravel-4-return-the-id-of-the-current-insert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent

Comment: @AmirBawab - None of which answer the OP's question.

Comment: @JosephSilber I suggested some answers because similar question were asked before

Comment: @AmirBawab - To repeat: none of those answer the question. The OP is aware of `insertGetId`, but wants a different column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to perform another query yourself:

```php
$id = DB::table($this->table)->insertGetId('...');

$thread_id = DB::table($this->table)->where('id', $id)->pluck('thread_id');
```